# Getting a query to work in Access over MSADO

Tags: c++, ms-access

I'm trying to get the last two of the following queries to work, but I can only get the first to work.

```
 querystream << "select Date, C"<<m_ID<<" from Data" <<nTable <<";";

 querystream << "select Date, C"<<m_ID<<" from Data" <<nTable <<" where Date >= #DateAdd (\"yyyy\", -1, Now())#  ORDER by DATE ASC;";
 querystream << "select Date, C"<<m_ID<<" from Data" <<nTable <<" where Date >= #DateAdd (\"yyyy\", -1, #10/09/2012 09:12#)#  ORDER by DATE ASC;";
```

If any of you have any ideas, I would be very grateful,
Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateAdd()` returns a Date/Time value, and the db engine can use its return value as is ... so you don't need to include the `#` delimiters.

`Date` is a reserved word.  If you're using it as the name of a field in your table, enclose it in square brackets to avoid confusing the db engine.

```
" where [Date] >= DateAdd(\"yyyy\", -1, #10/09/2012 09:12#) ORDER by [DATE] ASC;"
```

The db engine will accept single instead of double quotes with the interval argument (yyyy) for `DateAdd()`.  I don't know if this will complicate anything in c++, but I would try it this way:

```
" where [Date] >= DateAdd('yyyy', -1, #10/09/2012 09:12#) ORDER by [DATE] ASC;"
```

If you have Access available, I think you would be better off to create and test your queries with the Access query designer, then use the proven SQL in c++.

Comment: Thank you very much, absolutely brilliant! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
querystream << "select Date, C"<<m_ID<<" from Data" <<nTable <<" where Date >= DateAdd (\"yyyy\", -1, Now())  ORDER by DATE ASC;";
querystream << "select Date, C"<<m_ID<<" from Data" <<nTable <<" where Date >= DateAdd (\"yyyy\", -1, #10/09/2012 09:12#)  ORDER by DATE ASC;";
```

(Basically, drop the # before and after DateAdd function)

Also, it is a good idea to use #YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM# format for the second query (it will be either #2012-09-10 09:12# or #2012-10-09 09:12# in your example depending on your localisation settings